# How to retain exported file in docker image

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

I am migrating a java standalone maven project in docker. As of now we create a jar file for this maven project and it runs with public static void main method.

```
java -cp app.jar com.xxx.ExportManager db.properties
```

After completion of this code it exports a file in its current directory.

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/

ENV echo $JAVA_HOME

RUN  java -version

ARG JAR_FILE=target/manager.jar
ARG JAR_LIB_FILE=target/lib/

WORKDIR /opt/manager/app/

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

COPY conf/db.properties /opt/manager/app/db.properties

ADD ${JAR_LIB_FILE} lib/

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Commands:

- Building image: `docker build -t pc .`
- Run the main method: `docker run -t pc /opt/manager/app/db.properties`

After run it's exporting file inside image (I am sure because i have checked it through loggers) to /opt/manager/app/. But when i see the contents of image using command

```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh pc 
cd /opt/manager/app
```

the directory doesn't have exported file however it contains all other project files.

How to retain the exported file in the image?

PS: I'm new in docker, please forgive any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker run -it --entrypoint sh pc` actually starts a new container instead of starting a shell in a running one. So you are looking inside a new container where the exporting has not been done (because you overwrote the entry point).

To start a shell in a running container and attach your stdin/stdout to it, you need `exec` instead of `run`, e.g.:

```
docker exec -it pc bash
```

However in your particular scenario, you probably won't be able to start the shell anyway, because once the exporting is done, the container will be stopped. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833905/how-to-list-files-in-a-stopped-docker-container?noredirect=1&lq=1) for examining the filesystem of a stopped container.