# Copy files from container to local in Docker

Tags: docker

I want to copy a file from container to my local. The file is generated after execute python script, but due to then `ENTRYPOINT`, the container exited right after it run, and cant be able to use `docker cp` command. Any idea on how to `prevent` the container from exit before manage to copy the file? Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    rm -f /var/cache/apk/*

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]
```

I use this command to run the image:
`docker run -d -it --name test [image]`

Comment: Why can't you use `docker cp`? It works with stopped containers (to and from): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38356081/407651

Comment: @mzjn, it shows `Error: No such container:path: cont_name:/app/example.json` when i use this command: `docker run -d -it --name test [image] \ && docker cp cont_name:/app/example.json /local/path`. Cant use `&&` together?

Comment: Your container name is `test` so it should be `docker cp test:/app/example.json /local/path`

Comment: Mikael, yes, I did, `cont_name` is just for me to define container name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output file is stored in it's own directory (say `/app/output`) you can run: `docker run -d -it -v $PWD/output:/app/output/ --name test [image]` and the file will be in the `output` directory of the current directory.

If it's not, then run the container with: `docker run -d -it --name test [image]`
Then copy the file to your own filesystem using `docker cp test:/app/example.json .` to copy it to the current directory.

Comment: Mikael, I tried, but I cant see the output file in my local. :(

Comment: Which directory should the output be in?

Comment: In container, the file store in /app directory. 
docker run -d -it -v $PWD:/app/example.json  --name test [image]

Comment: In that case my solution does't work. Let me change the answer a little bit

Comment: Hi Mikael, it works if it execute separately, but when I combine the command like this: `docker run -d -it --name test [image] \ && docker cp test:/app/example.json .` , it shows this err: `Error: No such container:path: test:/app/example.json`. The reason is because the command is run in terraform, so i need to add `&&`.

Comment: Seems like the file doesn't exist then. Are you sure that's the output name?

Comment: It works well if I execute `docker run` then `docker cp`, but if add `&&` then it shows `Error: No such container:path: test:/app/example.json`

Comment: Did you try with `;` instead of `&&` in case the container doesn't exit nicely?

Comment: Yes i did try `;`,  but same error i got. Thank you for your solution, appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If running a container in background is unnecessary then you can copy a file from stdout

```sh
docker run -it [image] cat /app/example.json > out_example.json
```

Comment: This won't work since the container would have exited